# Prevent accessing files outside of given working directory

Tags: c

I am trying to prevent the access on files outside of a given working directory.
My first attempt was to use `chdir` and `chroot`, but `chroot` can only be used by root users.

Is there any other possibility? I have heard something about another one, but I can't remember.

Perhaps a simple function to check if the path is outside of the working directory or second argument.

Some details about the program:

- shall be run on Linux
- simple shell programm without any interactive elements
- takes a directory argument, which is the working directory

Thanks for any advices.

EDIT:
After some research I found different aproachments, but I can't use any of them.

- pivot_root
- set_fs_root (linux kernel)

Is there any possibility to use that?

Perhaps there is a possibility to open a file which is contained by a given directory. So I call the function with the argument file path and the "root" path where to look.

Comment: Are you writing a shell or something interactive? Give more details.

Comment: If its a shell, then you ought to have a command to chdir?

Comment: @tuxuday chdir works but I can always access files outside of my working directory

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're on a Linux/MacOSX platform. There are a couple of ways. One is to create a special user for your program who owns that directory, but doesn't have write permissions to anything else in the system*. The other option is to use a program like SELinux to only allow certain operations to the program, but that seems like overkill.

*: You must *always* give the user read permissions. How will your program run without read access to `glibc`?

Comment: Yeah correct, I am using Linux. I will add that in my question. The program shall be run as normal user and you can give a directory as argument. The program uses fopen and shall not access files which are outside of the working directory. There is no possibility to use SELinux or an own user for that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into a restricted shell; I think most of the common shells have options for a restricted mode that disables `cd`, prevents changes to certain environment variables, and some other things. For `pdksh`, it would be `/bin/ksh -r`. The option differ for other shells, though, so read the appropriate `man`ual page.

Comment: The user shall not open a restricted shell only start the program. Is there no option to check if the path is within the allowed path?